# Unable to clear input fields using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a simple page in ASP.NET Core 3.0. Using Blazor Framework.
Page has a SELECT as below:

```
<select id="AppSelect" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-secondary" >
                            <option value="-">--- Select ---</option>
                            <option value="-">Books</option>
</select>
```

On change of the Select List option, I want to fire a jQuery function which should empty any text in the Input fields of the Form.

I added a .js file under wwwroot folder with the code:

```
$(".form-control-sm").change(function () {
    $(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
});
```

I even tried this:

```
$("#AppSelect").change(function () {
    $(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
});
```

Seems it is not firing jQuery code and clearing the fields.

I added reference of .js in a file called _Host.cshtml which is under Pages folder.

The Input Fields are generated using this code:

```
          <!-- Input fields -->
            @for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                var index = i;
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <div class="justify-content-center mb-2">
                            <input class="form-control form-control-sm border border-secondary" @bind="booksmod.Id[index]" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="justify-content-center mb-2">
                            <input class="form-control form-control-sm border border-secondary" @bind="booksmod.Name[index]" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
```

Comment: Can you please add the HTML which you are trying to clear as well ? the `form` HTML

Comment: you need to include the js in your html page

Comment: @Chaz updated the post with details

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Added the code

Comment: where is `<form>` and input with type text?

Comment: Are all these fields inside a form including the `select` you are trying to trigger ?

Comment: _When_ does your JS code execute? Maybe you just need to wrap it in $.ready.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping These are inside <EditForm> tag. It is using Blazor plugin. I did not find any Form tag other than EditForm

Comment: Why not just call [`reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) on your `form`?

Comment: Blazor is not a plugin; it's a completely different framework. Look at the rendered HTML via view source or inspect element and provide that rendered HTML in your question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Ok. Let me execute.

Comment: Try `$("#AppSelect").change(function () { alert("ok") })` - do you get the alert (when you change the `select`)?  if not (and your description indicates this will not run) try `$(document).on("change", "#AppSelect", function () { alert("ok") });` - if that works, it's because your code is running before the element exists (possibly the "blazor" framework creating it via ajax?)

Comment: The question did not mention Blazor in any way. He should amend the question to make this clear rather than a comment

Comment: @Quango Yes my fault. I should be specific. I missed to add that before and mentioned in one of the comments above. Edited post.

Comment: Not a problem @RKh - just hope you managed to get your problem resolved..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your using Blazor as your comments suggest then there is no need to use jQuery to achieve this:

```
 <form>
    <div class="form-inline">
        <select class="form-control mr-1" @bind="@FruitType">
            <option value="@(string.Empty)">Select</option>
            <option value="apple">Apple</option>
            <option value="orange">Orange</option>
            <option value="pear">Pear</option>
        </select>
        <input class="form-control mr-1" placeholder="Name" @bind="fruit.Name"  />
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Colour" @bind="fruit.Color" />
    </div>
</form>

@code {
    public string FruitType
    {
        get => this.fruitType;
        set
        {
            if (this.fruitType == value) return;
            this.fruitType = value;
            ClearProperties();
        }
    }

    void ClearProperties()
    {
        fruit.Color = "";
        fruit.Name = "";
    }

    string fruitType = "";
    Fruit fruit = new Fruit();
}
```

[image]
#LookMaNoJava :)

Comment: Thanks. This solved my issue with Blazor Model. Modified the model and it works. Form tag also not required.

Answer (score 2):

I tested your code and had it working by using a wrapping form to the select input as well as the textareas and the text inputs as follow:

```
<form class="my-form">
  <select id="AppSelect" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-secondary" >
    <option value="-">--- Select ---</option>
    <option value="-">Books</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" />
  <textarea/>
</form>
```

If you want to keep the select out of the form, you should target your form more precisely, using a class as follow :

```
$(".form-control-sm").change(function () {
  $('form.my-form').find("input['type=text'], textarea").val("");
});
```

A good practice would be to set values that can be read or use to your select options for the sake of accessibility and undestandability.

**EDIT**: Your inputs are lacking a type="text" in your HTML, which prevents them from being selected by the css selector `input[type=text]`.

Comment: Let me check if adding a Form tag conflicts with any thing. Thanks.

Comment: I implemented the changes and also added type=text with the input fields. Still not working. I guess it is not working because of Blazor Framework. When I select "View Source" from the rendered page, I did not find any input fields in the HTML. It is appearing blank.

Comment: I see. So, nothing appears if you just log $('input') ?

Answer (score 1):

It works if you leave out the `[type=text]` in your CSS selector:

```js
$("select.form-control-sm").change(function () {
    $(this).closest('form').find("input,textarea").val("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id="AppSelect" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-secondary" >
   <option value="-">--- Select ---</option>
   <option value="-">Books</option>
   <option value="-">Magazines</option>
   <option value="-">Newspapers</option>
  </select>

<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="justify-content-center mb-2">
      <input class="form-control form-control-sm border border-secondary" id="id0" value="something" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="justify-content-center mb-2">
      <input class="form-control form-control-sm border border-secondary" name="name0" value="something" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="justify-content-center mb-2">
      <input class="form-control form-control-sm border border-secondary" id="id1" value="something" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="justify-content-center mb-2">
      <input class="form-control form-control-sm border border-secondary" name="name1" value="something" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="justify-content-center mb-2">
      <input class="form-control form-control-sm border border-secondary" id="id2" value="something" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="justify-content-center mb-2">
      <input class="form-control form-control-sm border border-secondary" name="name2" value="something" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Yes, and of course - "it goes without saying"  - you have to embed all of your `<select>` and `<input>` elements with a `<form>` element. Otherwise your `.closest('form')` won't have a chance of finding anything.

The way I tested it, it *won't* work with `[type=text]`, see below:

```js
$("select.form-control-sm").change(function () {
    $(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text],textarea").val("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id="AppSelect" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-secondary" >
   <option value="-">--- Select ---</option>
   <option value="-">Books</option>
   <option value="-">Magazines</option>
   <option value="-">Newspapers</option>
  </select>

<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="justify-content-center mb-2">
      <input class="form-control form-control-sm border border-secondary" id="id0" value="something" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="justify-content-center mb-2">
      <input class="form-control form-control-sm border border-secondary" name="name0" value="something" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="justify-content-center mb-2">
      <input class="form-control form-control-sm border border-secondary" id="id1" value="something" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="justify-content-center mb-2">
      <input class="form-control form-control-sm border border-secondary" name="name1" value="something" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="justify-content-center mb-2">
      <input class="form-control form-control-sm border border-secondary" id="id2" value="something" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="justify-content-center mb-2">
      <input class="form-control form-control-sm border border-secondary" name="name2" value="something" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: *It works if you leave out the [type=text]* - Well it will work by adding `[type=text]` as well as long the HTML OP structure is correct.

Comment: Hmmm, @AlwaysHelping: it doesn't seem to work in my snippet. See above. :-(

Comment: If all inputs and select is in one form it should work. Seeing OP's HTML structure is important to provide an accurate answer. Work fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/way398b7/

Comment: Yes, your fiddle works because you have `type="text"` in the HTML of your input elements. From what the OP provided I could not safely assume that his input elements would *also* have these type assignments in them. But this uncertainty might stem from my ignorance with respect to the behaviour of ASP.NET pages. ;-)

Comment: Correct. The way HTML in rendered in OP's page is `unknown` and we (us) can only make assumptions to what the actual accurate answer would be without seeing the actual HTML - OP mentioned aboue blazor framework :-)